# How to add custom address fields to checkout page?

Tags: shopware

I need to add custom fields to checkout page, especially to address block and also validate it.. I use Shopware 6 and there is no really documentation about that ((

More explanations: I want to implement possibility to choice the address and street from selectable dropdown (from my database), such a way will not possible to set wrong address. And also I want to implement specific delivery method - and for that I need one field more, in this field customer will type the station number of this new delivery service...

In my opinion I should do several things:

1. Extend order entity with new fields
2. Extend checkout template and display new fields
3. Add new controller to send ajax request to fetch autocompletes
4. Extend back-end order template to show new fields

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add your custom fields? On the checkout page near the billing address or to the popup where customer can modify or add an address?

Comment: both places.. I added explanations to my question.. Help is mega appreciated because problem with documentation..((

Comment: Ok. So you want to replace the existing street field with your own dropdown field? Do you want to store the station number in the database, for example as custom field?

Comment: @PawełNapierała, yes right I need to replace street field with my own dropdown field. And yes I need to store the station number in the database

Comment: @Mikael Can you please add details / code to the question what you tried so far?